# The priority of Promise,async/await,setTimeout

Tags: javascript, async-await, promise, settimeout

```
async function a() {
  console.log("a");
}
async function b() {
  console.log("b1");
  await a();
  console.log("b2");
}
setTimeout(() => {
  console.log("setTimeout");
}, 0);
b();
new Promise((resolve) => {
  console.log("p1");
  resolve();
}).then(() => {
  console.log("p2");
});
console.log("end");
```

The above code will output：

```
"b1"
"a"
"p1"
"end"
"b2"
"p2"
"setTimeout"
```

I understand the first output is "b1" and the second is "a" but why the third output is not "b2"?

The output I thought is

```
"b1"
"a"
"b2"
"p1"
"end"
"p2"
"setTimeout"
```

I understand the order of the Promise and setTimeout function, just can't figure out the order of "b2".

Comment: it really depends on your javascript engine's implementation. they all have different queues for different types of callbacks

Comment: "Note that promises are guaranteed to be asynchronous. Therefore, an action for an already "settled" promise will occur only after the stack has cleared and a clock-tick has passed." https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise

Comment: Usually, it's first in, first out, and since the method calling "b2" came into the list of promise checks that need to be done every cycle first, it gets executed first. Just imagine everytime you await the entire next bit of code being wrapped and placed in a queue array that gets evaluated one by one every cycle. If the promise is resolved, the method gets executed and removed from the queue. Since b() is called first, every one of its steps will be resolved before any later ones.

Comment: Recommending looking into [tasks and microtasks](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTML_DOM_API/Microtask_guide) to know how `setTimeout()` and promises go into queue, and the order they're processed.

Answer (score 3):

> why the third output is not "b2"?

It's gotta finish running all the synchronous code first. Only after that can it resume after the `await`.

This code starts by defining some functions, then it sets a timeout, then calls `b()`. `b` logs out "b1", then calls `a` which logs out "a" and returns a promise, then `b` `await`s that promise. The `await` keyword means that `b` immediately returns, and returns a promise. Next, the code calls `new Promise`, which immediately runs the constructor function, logging "p1" and moving the promise to the resolved state. Next it calls `.then` on the promise queuing up some code to run in the future, and finally it logs out "end".

Now we're done with all the synchronous stuff, so then we can get to resuming asynchronous stuff such as "b2".